# Java : Replace a specific char in string to it is index

Tags: java, string, replace, complexity-theory

Is there any faster way to replace $ in $som$thing
to 0som4thing ( change the $ to its index ) 
other then for loop and the charAt(i)

Comment: You could use a `StringBuilder` and a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Other than using a mapper on a Stream instead of a for-loop, I wouldn't know of a way to do that. Usually a stream is a little faster in my experience 'though, but that might be somewhat subjective.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I cannot think of anything that would be magnitudes faster (and I'm pretty sure this really is premature optimization), but using an enhanced for loop might buy some milliseconds in range checks - I just think it's not worth using it in this case.</strike>The already mentioned StringBuffer might actually make the bigger difference. Just stick with the standard for loop, alternatives might or might not be faster, but probably less readable.

Comment: Use [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) in preference to [`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html).

Comment: You're right...I would actually know it better, might be just tired. >.<

Comment: This actually might be slightly slower, as it requires creating the returned `char[]`. This has a clearer performance penalty in the string compression changes coming in jdk 9.

Comment: Hm...maybe... looks like _someone_ should check how it would compare to getting each single char from a compressed string...not me!